# Unable to Edit Properties on SharePoint Service Provider

Tags: 2007, search, central-administration, shared-service-provider

I am trying to assign an indexer on our SharePoint Service Provide. However, every time I go to edit properties on the SSP. I get this:

> An unhandled exception occurred in the user interface.Exception
>   Information: The specified account name is invalid. 
>       Parameter name: account

My account has access to SP Admin and I have also tried accessing the site with all other Admin Accounts.

Is there any other reason why I wouldn't be able to view these properties?

**Side Note:**

I was following this documentation for applying an indexer, which I have used before on this site and it previously worked:

http://bytelab.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/indexer-is-not-assigned-to-shared.html

**Edit:**

When I visit the Shared Service Administration and select "Search Settings". I get this.

> An indexer is not assigned to the Shared Services Provider
>   'SharedServices1'.
>
> Configure an indexer and a search database for this Shared Services
>   Provider

When I click to configure an indexer I get a `404 page not found`. (Just trying to provide as much information as possible.